# How to solve this equation? $ y'' + y = 4xe^x $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that  $ y'' + y = 4xe^x $ is a sort of unhomogeneous diff equation and that a general solution would include a combo of both the unhomogeneous and the homogeneous solution, and that the geometric and algebraic multitude s,  and n play a role here....but I am not certain of their definition nor how to combine it all.

Comment: Can you give a general solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation $y''+y=0$ ? What sort of techniques do you know for non-homogeneous equations? Undetermined Coefficients? Variation of Parameters?

Comment: This was explained in class - probably you should not have skipped that day. It's also explained, with examples, in the book.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What exactly makes you assume I skipped class that day, and moreover what makes you assume anything about me whatsoever?

Comment: The fact that you're totally stumped by an exercise that's trivial by a method that was explained in class...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Just out of interest, could you please tell me which book you are referring to for Differential Equations?

Comment: I _am_ assuming that you're taking a class in DE - the reason I assume that is that's true for the vast majority of trivial questions we see here. If you're taking a class then I'm referring to the text for the class. If you're actually not taking a class I'm referring to whatever book you're studying. (If you're trying to learn this stuff without any book at all that's a bad idea - get a book on DE.)

Answer (score 7):

As $1$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial (of the (homogeneous) differential operator on the left side), the degree of the polynomial factor stays the same and you have to try to fit the parameters in
$$
y_p(x)=(ax+b)e^x
$$
to the equation.

Comment: This is known as the method of undetermined coefficients, right?

Comment: Yes, in its most simple case without resonances.

Answer (score 2):

$$y''+y=4xe^x$$

the characteristic equation is $m^2+1=0$ with solutions $m_{12}=\pm\ i$

$$\mathbf{y_{h}(x)=C_1 \cos(x)+C_2\sin(x)}$$

from here you can use *Undetermined Coefficients*  or *Variation of parameters*
\begin{align}
y_p(x)&=(Ax+B)e^x
\\~
\\
y'_p(x)&=Ae^x+Axe^x+Be^x
\\
y''_p(x)&=2Ae^x+Axe^x+Be^x
\end{align}
replace in the ODE
$$
(2Ae^x+Axe^x+Be^x)+(Axe^x+Be^x)=4xe^x
\\
(2A+2B)e^x+2Axe^x=4xe^x
$$
then $ A=2$ and $ B=-2$
$$\mathbf{y_p(x)=2(x-1)e^x}
\\~\\ 
\mathbf{y(x)=C_1 \cos(x)+C_2\sin(x)+2(x-1)e^x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$$$Here is an alternate solution using the Method of Annihilators:$$$$
$y_1=4xe^x$ is clearly annihilated by $D^2-2D+1=(D-1)^2$ where $D$ denotes the derivative operator. Hence, using this annihilator on both sides of the original ODE, the ODE can be "rewritten" as $$(D^2+1)(D-1)^2y=(D+i)(D-i)(D-1)^2y=0$$ $$$$Edit: As pointed out in the comments, after getting the solutions to the equation $(D^2+1)(D-1)^2y=(D+i)(D-i)(D-1)^2y=0$, we need to see which solutions actually satisfy the original equation - the calculations there are going to be exactly like if we used Undetermined Coefficients.

Comment: Saying you've "rewritten" the equation is at best misleading, because most solutions to the "rewritten" equation are _not_ solutions to the original equation.

Comment: We need to look at the general solution to the "rewritten" equation and see which solutions actually satisfy the original equation - the calculations there are going to be exactly like if we used Undetermined Coefficients. (This nonetheless has a good deal of merit, in that it's clear that it should work, as opposed to the magic in the typical exposition of Undetermined Coefficients.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes you're right of course, after evaluating the solution to $(D^2+1)(D−1)^22y=(D+i)(D−i)(D−1)^2y=0$ one must check which of the solutions will actually "work" by comparing coefficients. At the time of writing the solution I could not think of any other word apart from 'rewritten'; I am modifying the solution now.

Comment: "If $y$ is a solution to the original DE then $y$ is also a solution to..."